# Using the python enum module for ctypes

Tags: python, enums, ctypes

Before the `enum` module existed, `c_int` or related types were often used as substitute enums. But this did not have nor check for types.

Now that python has an `enum` module, is there a way to use that directly with `ctypes`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can easily create our own CEnum class thanks to ctypes allowing us the option to use custom classes. Enum types are checked automatically by ctypes.

```
from ctypes import windll
from enum import IntEnum


class CEnum(IntEnum):
    @classmethod
    def from_param(cls, self):
        if not isinstance(self, cls):
            raise TypeError
        return self


class EnumA(CEnum):
    CONST = 0


class EnumB(CEnum):
    CONST = 0
```

Here's an example (which abuses types, but shows the usage correctly):

```
windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleA.argtypes = [EnumA]

>>> windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleA(EnumA.CONST)
>>> windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleA(EnumB.CONST)
ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>:
```

*As an aside*, I've since switched to [cffi](https://cffi.readthedocs.org/), which supports enums natively, and uses c definitions which happens to be a lot more concise compared to their ctype counterparts.

Comment: I don't get any `ValueError` when I run your code on Python 3.4.1 -- also the error message shown seems odd, wouldn't it be `ValueError: 0 is not a valid EnumA`?

Comment: @eryksun Hmm, not sure how that happened, fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't allow me to use `CEnum` subclasses as C types in `ctypes.Structure` definitions. I've made a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877391/using-an-intenum-as-the-type-in-a-ctypes-structure-fields) for this.