# Using an IntEnum as the type in a ctypes.Structure._fields_

Tags: python, enums, ctypes

I would like to make one of the fields of my `ctypes.Structure` an enum. This [post](http://www.chriskrycho.com/2015/ctypes-structures-and-dll-exports.html) suggests adding a `from_param` classmethod to the enum class, but claims that this isn't enough for a custom `ctypes.Structure`. I've also tried inheriting from both `enum.IntEnum` and `ctypes.c_uint` but that results a metaclass conflict. Here is approximately what I want:

```
class MyEnum(enum.IntEnum):
    A = 0
    B = 1

class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('my_enum', MyEnum),
        ...
    ]
```

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27199479/208880)?

Comment: I had not seen that question, but I've tried the approach given in that answer and it gives me `TypeError: second item in _fields_ tuple (index 0) must be a C type` even if I subclass the `CEnum` type they create.

Comment: The `from_param` hook is called to convert a function argument to a type that ctypes can use directly. It doesn't enable using an arbitrary type in a C aggregate type (i.e. `ctypes.Array`, `ctypes.Structure`, or `ctypes.Union`) or as the `_type_` of a `ctypes._Pointer`.

Comment: You can subclass `ctypes.c_int` to create an enum class that overrides `__new__` to restrict instantiation and implements the class methods `_check_retval_` and `from_param` to restrict the value for a given result or argument. However, there's no hook to restrict the value to get from or set to an aggregate type or dereferenced pointer, not without using ctypes to hack itself to implement a custom `getfunc` and `setfunc` for the type.